# Why the basis of $-x+y-z=0$ has two vectorial solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let be $A$
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & -1\\ -1 & 3 & -1\\ -1 & 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> and $f\in L(\mathbb R^3)$ cannonically associated to $A$.
>
> How can I determine the basis of $\ker (f-2id)$?

I understand that $(x,y,z)\in\ker (f-2id)$ iif it is solution of $AX=2X$ where $X=(xyz)^T$.
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x&+y&-z&=2x\\
-x&+3y&-z&=2y\\
-x&+y&+z&=2z
\end{cases}\\
\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
-x&+y&-z&=0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The answer is then the basis $\{\vec u_2(1,0,-1),\vec u_3(0,1,1)\}$ but I don't understand why there is two vectors. I notice that they both realize the given conditions.

**edit:** I was also wondering why are $\ker (f-2id)$ and $\ker (f-id)$ supplementary in $\mathbb R^3$? In understand the geometrical definition of supplementarity, but not the algebraic one.

Comment: The system you are writing is for $\ker (f-2Id)$, and $2$ is the other eigenvalue. And in your case, $1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$, while $2$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$. And, when an eigenvalue has muliplicity $k>1$, the eigenspace may have dimension up to $k$ (but may be as low as $1$).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, I edited! But how did you knew that it actually was an eigenvalue?

Comment: Since you proved the matrix $A-2I$ has rank $1$, I know $det(A-2I)=0$, thus $2$ is an eigenvalue. I know the multiplicity is $\geq2$ since the associated eigenspace has dimension $2$, and there is another eigenvalue ($1$) you mention, so the muliplicity of the eigenvalue $2$ can't be more than $2$ (the matrix has $3$ eigenvalues, counting multiplicity).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Has matrix $A-2I$ rank $1$ because there is only one equation within it?

Comment: Because $(A-2I)X=0$ is reduced to a single equation, yes. It's equivalent to say that by row operations, you get a matrix with only one nonzero row, that is, the other two rows are simply multiples of this one, and the row-rank is $1$. See *[rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29)* on Wikipedia, for more details about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution has two vectors, since you get three variables and only one equation: you have two free parameters. taking your last expression$$-x+y-z=0$$
as independent solutions you can take, for example the case with $x=1,y=0$, which leads to $z=-1$ and $x=1,y=0$ which leads to $z=1$. Then the vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ generate the space of your solution. Note that any other choice of the values of the free parameters will lead to a similar solution, with only a change of the basis.

Comment: Okay, I edited. Thanks! So, when I have one equation and three variables and two free parameters **therefore** two vectors in the basis. Am I right?

Comment: Sure! because you can always choose the free parameters to define two independent vectors